# Avoid mobs from spawning automatically

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a swimming pool in Minecraft and squids are spawned automatically in the water

I tried to set difficulty to Peaceful but it not working

Any solution?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's possible. You could reduce the chance they will spawn in your pool by making sure there's plenty of water nearby for squid to spawn in (perhaps next to a lake, ocean, or even some artificial pools built underground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the `doMobSpawning` gamerule to prevent mobs spawning naturally:

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

You will need to have cheats enabled to run the above command. If you have not, you can temporarily enable them by the following:

1. Open the menu while on the world (<kbd>ESC</kbd>)
2. Press <kbd>Open to LAN</kbd>
3. Switch <kbd>Allow Cheats</kbd> to `ON`, then press <kbd>Start LAN World</kbd>

Comment: I tried this, I don't know if it works, when verify that it works, I will accept the answer